# AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictWriter'

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I keep getting an attribute error from the following code.

```
import csv
myFile = open('countries.csv', 'w')
with myFile:    
    myFields = ['country', 'capital']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=myFields)    
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'country' : 'France', 'capital': 'Paris'})
    writer.writerow({'country' : 'Italy', 'capital': 'Rome'})
    writer.writerow({'country' : 'Spain', 'capital': 'Madrid'})
    writer.writerow({'country' : 'Russia', 'capital': 'Moscow'})
```

any ideas

Comment: do you have your own module DictWriter.py in same directory?

Comment: no actually right now even ```csv.writer``` gives the same error

Comment: its like the csv package is the one with the problem

Comment: I solved the error. I had placed the file with this script in a folder and python was trying to import the csv module from the same folder instead of using the ```python csv module```.